# SharePoint 2010 Site Collection Quota - changed but not taking effect?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, quota

I have users getting the Site Collection Quota exceeded error message in SP2010. I have increased the limit in Central Admin to 80gb out of which only 5gb are being used. BUT they are still getting this error? Is there something I need to reset before the change takes effect?

I have no idea where else to change the quota limit. I have changed it for all of our site collections and MySites as well so I'm not sure why the error still shows up.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I got from the Logs: (not sure how to paste this in a better format)

> 03/20/2013 11:42:02.19    w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)
>     0x11FC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Site=/  3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485 03/20/2013
>   11:42:02.22   w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)                           0x11FC  Document
>   Management Server     Document Management             52od    Medium 
>     MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart
>   was found on this
>   page[/_layouts/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b606C45DD-4396-486B-856B-33F45AFDDC6A%7d&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1].
>   Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy
>   ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this
>   list. 3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485 03/20/2013 11:42:02.24
>     w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)                           0x11FC  SharePoint Foundation
>     General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error
>   occurred. More information:
>   0x80070002    3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485 03/20/2013 11:42:02.28
>     w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)                           0x11FC  SharePoint Foundation
>     General                         8kh7    High        Your changes could not
>   be saved because this SharePoint Web site has exceeded the storage
>   quota limit. You must save your work to another location.  Contact
>   your administrator to change the quota limits for the Web
>   site. 3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485 03/20/2013 11:42:02.28
>     w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)                           0x11FC  SharePoint Foundation
>     Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Your
>   changes could not be saved because this SharePoint Web site has
>   exceeded the storage quota limit. You must save your work to another
>   location.  Contact your administrator to change the quota limits for
>   the Web site.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile,
>   Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String
>   bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object
>   varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties,
>   String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64
>   fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String
>   bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId,
>   Int32 min...  3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485 03/20/2013
>   11:42:02.28*  w3wp.exe (0x1CA0)
>     0x11FC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...utes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32
>   bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus,
>   String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32&
>   pbIgnoredReqProps)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String
>   bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM,
>   PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy,
>   Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object
>   varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment,
>   Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String
>   bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String
>   bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32
>   fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32&
>   pdwVirusCheckSt...    3184a70c-4e05-440c-b742-7437e119d485

Comment: did you followed all of these steps for increasing limits, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263480(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The content DB in which your site collection resides is in read-only mode, you need to change it back to read/write mode.

For example,

[image]

Here's a [post](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=329) that can help you putting it back to read & write state.

[image]

Comment: Actually mine says No under Database Read-Only and I have checked and there are 90gb of free space on the database server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why it was happening but I think it is fixed now. I had to go to Configure Quotas and Locks and change the Current Quota Template to Individual then select Ok, then come back and switch back to the Template I created. I guess this is what it needed to refresh and use the updated quota?

Not sure but it seems to be working now. I will monitor for a few days and close the question then.